# Setting specific macro only run for certain file extension on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, go, macros, intellij-14

I have a `macro` on IntelliJ that format the code then save:

[image: formatted save]

I have assigned keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+S` to that macro:

[image: assigned shortcut]

This works well for `css`, `js`, and `html`.

The problem is, the built-in [go-lang-idea-plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) gives different result from [`gofmt`](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) (formatter program that called by my auto-reload/auto-recompile program [`gin`](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin) that runs when the sources changed/saved on disk) 
so the `ReformatCode` command for `.go` source code is useless.

How to disable that macro only for `.go` file? So when I save using `Ctrl+S`, it only do `SaveAll`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the File Watcher plugin instead of macros to solve this issue: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/1324#issuecomment-75263115

Comment: no, my `gin`+`go fmt` program works just fine, the problem is the `reformat code` for go doesn't work as expected..

Comment: Then I think you have a different problem, reported here: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/1215